# Excecuting mysql querys in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

im using the insert php code plugin in wordpress and im trying to do inserts and mysql querys, but there's an error that appears me:

```
Error: INSERT INTO porschec_clientes.clientes(
ID,
NAME,
LAST_NAME,
EMAIL,
PHONE,
PORSCHE,
REFERENCE,
STATUS
CODE,
)
VALUES (NULL,’name’,’last_name’,’email@gmail.com’,’123123′,’911′,’name’, 0, ‘cdcc34cd554621097f9a6fdc3b2cc728′)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ‘CODE,
)
```

look that in "CODE" there's this quote symbol " ‘ " (i dont know if the correct translation is quote but... whatever haha) but in my php code i have it this way

```
  VALUES (NULL,'name','last_name','email@gmail.com','123123′,'911′,'name', 0, 'cdcc34cd554621097f9a6fdc3b2cc728')";
```

wordpress is changing the quote symbol when i update the page, there's any way that i can avoid this? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a `,`after `STATUS`, that's what the error tells you. Usually it shows the part after the error.

```
REFERENCE,
STATUS, <--
CODE,
```

Beside that let it change the quotes. That's all right.